# ordering query by parent-->sub

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I currently have a navigation menu which grabs parent items from a MySQL table.

I plan to implement sub-menu items, however instead of having another query inside of the parent query, I want to be able to grab all of the navigation items in order of parent --> sub in one query.

So for example:

```
Parent
      Sub
      Sub
Parent
      Sub
Parent
Parent
      Sub
         Sub
```

The current code I have is:

```
    <?php
    if($grabNav = $db->prepare("SELECT caption,url,visibility,id,class,parent_id FROM navigation ORDER BY parent_id ASC, order_id ASC"))
    {
        $grabNav->execute();
        $grabNav = $grabNav->fetchAll();
        foreach($grabNav as $nav)
        {
            $visibility = true;
            switch($nav['visibility'])
            {
                default:
                case 0: $visibility = false; break;
                case 1: $visibility = true; break;
                case 2: if(LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser)) { $visibility = true; } else { $visibility = false; } break;
                case 3: if(LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser)) { $visibility = false; } else { $visibility = true; } break;
            }
            if(!$visibility) { continue; }

            $class = $core->output($nav['class']);
            if($nav['id'] == PAGE_ID) { $class .= ' selected'; }
            echo '<li class="'.$class.'"><a href="'.$core->output($nav['url']).'">'.$core->output($nav['caption'],true).'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

How would I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Pack only your output logic into a function, and call it recursively for submenu entries. Use $parent_id=0 or recurse with $parent_id=$id etc. and just keep a reference to your fetchAll array.